# reading text file columns one after another in a 1D array

Tags: file-io, fortran, text-files

I have tried to read the following text file using Fortran. The text file has 24 rows and 15 columns. I want to put all the data in a single column array z. I wanted to read the 1st column then the 2nd then 3rd until the end.
Here is my data:

```
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0.16    0.16    0.17    0.18    0.19    0.19    0.19    0.19    0.18    0.18    0.18    0.18
0   0   0   0.31    0.33    0.35    0.37    0.37    0.39    0.39    0.37    0.37    0.37    0.37    0.37
0   0   0   0.47    0.49    0.52    0.55    0.56    0.58    0.58    0.56    0.55    0.55    0.55    0.55
0   0   0   0.48    0.51    0.55    0.59    0.6 0.61    0.61    0.59    0.59    0.59    0.59    0.59
0   0   0   0.48    0.53    0.57    0.62    0.63    0.64    0.63    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62
10  34  0   0.49    0.55    0.6 0.66    0.68    0.69    0.68    0.67    0.67    0.67    0.67    0.67
0   0   0   0.49    0.57    0.63    0.7 0.72    0.73    0.73    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72
0   0   0   0.49    0.59    0.65    0.75    0.77    0.78    0.77    0.77    0.77    0.77    0.77    0.77
0   0   0   0.49    0.61    0.68    0.79    0.81    0.83    0.82    0.81    0.82    0.82    0.82    0.82
0   0   0   0.49    0.63    0.7 0.83    0.86    0.87    0.87    0.86    0.87    0.87    0.87    0.87
0   0   0   0.49    0.65    0.73    0.87    0.9 0.92    0.92    0.91    0.92    0.92    0.92    0.92
0   0   0   0.49    0.67    0.76    0.91    0.95    0.97    0.96    0.95    0.97    0.97    0.97    0.97
0   0   0   0.49    0.69    0.78    0.95    0.99    1.01    1.01    1   1.02    1.02    1.02    1.02
0   0   0   0.49    0.71    0.81    0.99    1.04    1.06    1.06    1.05    1.07    1.07    1.07    1.07
0   0   0   0.49    0.73    0.83    1.04    1.08    1.11    1.1 1.09    1.11    1.11    1.11    1.11
0   0   0   0.49    0.75    0.86    1.08    1.13    1.15    1.15    1.14    1.16    1.16    1.16    1.16
0   0   0   0.49    0.77    0.88    1.12    1.18    1.2 1.2 1.19    1.21    1.21    1.21    1.21
0   0   0   0.49    0.77    0.88    1.12    1.18    1.2 1.2 1.19    1.21    1.21    1.21    1.21
0   0   0   0.49    0.77    0.88    1.12    1.18    1.2 1.2 1.19    1.21    1.21    1.21    1.21
24  48  72  0.49    0.77    0.88    1.12    1.18    1.2 1.2 1.19    1.21    1.21    1.21    1.21
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
program readdata
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
  implicit none

  integer :: i, j, k
  real :: z(360)
  integer :: iostat
  character(len=255) :: filename

  ! Set the text file name
  filename = 'D:/Shuvashish/Oyster Shaye/growth_z_for_sal_tem.txt'

  ! Open the text file
  open(15, file=filename, status='old',form='formatted')

  ! Read the data from the text file into the z array
  k = 1
  do j = 1, 15   ! j is changing
    do i = 1, 24 ! when j=2 and k=25, iostat becomes -1
      read(15,*,iostat=iostat) z(k)
      if (iostat < 0) exit ! exit loop if iostat is negative
      k = k + 1
    end do

  end do

  ! Close the text file
  close(15)

  ! Print the values of z
  do k = 1, 360
    print*, z(k)
  end do

end program readdata
```

Whenever, the loop finishes reading the last element of the 1st column, `iostat` becomes -1 and after that the it doesn't read the other columns. I am an absolute begineer in Fortran. Please let me know how to make the code work. Thanks.

Comment: Usr tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. Fortran 90 is just one very old revision of the standard that was quickly superseded by Fortran 95 and later other revisions.

Comment: Why don't you use a 2D array instead of a long 1D array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
read(15,*,iostat=iostat) z(k)
```

you will actually read an entire row ... but you will discard all but the first element. Thus, you can only do this 24 times and you will end up only storing the first column.

But when we read or write text we read from left to right (apologies to Leonardo da Vinci and anybody else writing from right to left!) and do so line by line. Similarly for computer files.

So, if you insist on reading into a 1-d array, (actually, you might find life easier if you read into a 2-d array), then read it ROW-BY-ROW first, then "transpose" to COLUMN-BY-COLUMN afterwards. (To be honest, do you really have to store your data column by column? You could easily have the i index denoting a column rather than a row.)

To read that file and subsequently store it in a 1-d array as first column, followed by second column, followed by third column etc, try the following.

```
program readdata
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: ni = 24, nj = 15
  character(len=*), parameter :: filename = "input.txt"

  integer i, j
  real rowByRow(ni*nj), columnByColumn(ni*nj)

  ! Read the text file ROW-BY-ROW
  open( 15, file=filename )
  read( 15, * ) rowByRow
  close( 15 )

  ! Transpose it to store COLUMN-BY-COLUMN
  do j = 1, nj
     columnByColumn( (j-1)*ni+1 : j*ni ) = rowByrow( j : : nj )
  end do

  ! Test write
  j = 5
  print "( a, i0 )", "Column ", j
  print "( f5.2 )", columnByColumn( (j-1)*ni + j : j*ni )

end program readdata
```

For example, the 5th column:

```
Column 5
 0.16
 0.33
 0.49
 0.51
 0.53
 0.55
 0.57
 0.59
 0.61
 0.63
 0.65
 0.67
 0.69
 0.71
 0.73
 0.75
 0.77
 0.77
 0.77
 0.77
```

Comment: The transposition could be done directly while reading the file: `do i = 1, ni ; read(15,*) columnbycolumn(ni::nj) ; end do`. Or even clearer with a 2D pointer: `p(1:ni,1:nj) => columnbycolumn(:) ; do i = 1, ni ; read(15,*) p(ni;:); end do`

Answer (score 1):

Fortran reads across rows. Fortran also has the caveat that when a read statement is done it moves the file pointer to the next line and skips the rest of the current line!

If you use the implied do loop in the read statement and do not mind a little math for the array index, this can be done very easily. Note the i do loop is the outer do loop for each of the 24 rows.

Implied do loops allow you to read multiple items from one line in a read statement. I also had the implied do loop go from 0 to 14 instead of 1 to 15 to keep the math simpler in the array index.

```
program readdata
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
  implicit none
  
  integer :: i, j, k
  real :: z(360)
  integer :: iostat
  character(len=255) :: filename

  ! Set the text file name
  filename = 'D:/Shuvashish/Oyster Shaye/growth_z_for_sal_tem.txt'

  ! Open the text file
  open(15, file=filename, status='old',form='formatted')

  ! Read the data from the text file into the z array
  do i = 1, 24
    read(15,*,iostat=iostat) (z(i+j*15), j=0,14)
    if (iostat < 0) exit ! exit loop if iostat is negative
  end do

  ! Close the text file
  close(15)

  ! Print the values of z
  do k = 1, 360
    print*, z(k)
  end do

end program readdata
```